# SP executing very slow and creating locks on objects

Tags: sql-server

There is a procedure on sql01 server extracting data from one of the table and inserting into Sql04 server(where applications are running).
There are arround 50000 Records and every time this executes, the procedure truncates data on Sql04 and inserts new data onto it.
The procedure is as below.

```
DELETE [SQL04].[Phantom].[dbo].[BulkQuote]
INSERT [SQL04].[Phantom].[dbo].[BulkQuote]  
(
 COL1, ___ COL22
)
SELECT   
COL1, ___ COL22
FROM [dbo].[Quote]
```

The above procedure is taking nearly an hour to get completly executed which is too long compared to the data that is there.

I have checked for other processes that are running on the same object at the same time and creating locks or blocks and found no blocks 
but the procedure is creating locks on the table (X and IX).

When i checked the SPID of job using SP_who2 then i got the below details
spid: 160
status: sleeping
Login: mcd\srvr02
Host: Sql02
BlkBy: -
DbName: Phantom
Command: Awaiting Command
CPU Time: 11475
DiskIO: 1106
Last Batch: 05/16 08:13:54

Someone please help me out in providing any information that could help me sort the locks and make the SP run quick.

Comment: Looks like you're doing a linked server query; those can be notoriously slow. Is it, however, the `DELETE` or `INSERT` that's slow? You could likely speed up the `DELETE` bu using `TRUNCATE` instead; provided you don't have an `IDENTITY` column you don't need to retain the numbering on. If it's the `INSERT`, then doing that over a linked server is likely to suffer performance problems, however, please also post the `DDL` of the indexes your table `[dbo].[Quote]`.

Comment: Using a linked server for an ETL process is always going to have performance problems.  You'd be better off switching to SSIS.